# Error: Cannot find symbol class view

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn developing Android Apps and I'm following the Training on developer.android.com

I've run into quite a bit of a problem while trying to open a new activity when a user clicks a button. I followed the instructions precisely and still can't figure out the problem

I compiled the code and got an error:

### Error:(39, 29) error: cannot find symbol class View

The code on line 39 is the following:

```
public void sendMessage (View view) {
```

I'm using Android Studio 0.5.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you import android.view.View

import android.view.View;

Answer (score 23):

I just ran into this same issue; Sripathi's suggestion worked.

```
 import android.view.View;
```

worked like a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I was also facing the same problem. "cannot find symbol class View"

Please import file given below

```
import android.view.View;
```

in `MainActivity.java` file

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv So you see a different question in this post? Really? And *"This does not really answer the question."* is obviously nonsense. If you want this post to be deleted during review, then use a proper comment for this.